# 3 Days to drive from Las Vegas to Los Angeles

Tags: usa, driving, sightseeing, los-angeles, las-vegas

I'm visiting the US for the first time and will stay for a couple of days in Las Vegas but, before catching the flight back to Europe (in Las Vegas), I'll have 3 whole days to get to know a bit of the surroundings! So this means I'm starting those 3 days on a Friday in Vegas and have to catch a flight on Monday in Vegas!

My plan is to rent a car for those 3 days and use it to get to places faster and to save some money by sleeping in it! I'm thinking of focusing in the Los Angeles area and **would like to know your suggestions on places to visit and itineraries I should take**.

Here's a couple of items I have on my list

- Ride a bike from Santa Monica to Manhattan Beach
- Visit Hollywood
- Watch a ball game
- Visit Joshua Tree
- Find out where can I rent a locker near Santa Monica
- Find out where can I safely park the car and sleep

So... what are your ideas?

Thanks!

Ricardo Neto
Lisbon - PT

Comment: Hi and welcome to travel.SE. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Hi, I'd like to know your suggestions on places to visit during these 3 days, possible itineraries.... what you think may help!

Comment: For the bike ride, I would start at Venice Beach and take it to Redondo Beach instead of Santa Monica to Manhattan Beach.  Prettier.  But it's an OPINION and everybody has one.  And there's no way for you to select a 'correct' opinion without slighting the others.  Close voting as 'opinion-based'

Comment: I'd consider driving to Zion National Park, the Grand Canyon (both sides if you're keen), Sedona, Lake Havasu, and the Hoover Dam. But that's just me.

Comment: So many opinions, so little time, so big  world ... :-). We travelled: Vegas, noted now but not then world wide drone sending USAFB as we passed, almost got to Area 51 as we turned left through Armagosa  (Opera house - amazing), church (shipping container with air cons - humbling & astounding), Baker - Shoeshon  - names out of John Wayne Movies. Death Valley (quick whip through but astounding) Dante's peak, Badwater (51-52 degrees?) , Stovepipe Wells , Lone Pine (The Dow where The Duke used to stay) Mono Lake (flies non contact Wow) , xxx high pass - snow in then hottest summer - Yosemite ....

Comment: ... upper and lower = different worlds, Tuolumne meadows - oh yes!, half dome & friends, ... Altimont pass dead windmills galore ... SF .| Whatr am I doing here? I was meant to be in LA. | OK SF look. Bubba Gump flit past, 101 ... Big Sur, Monterery, Hearst castle, more more ... LA. Here we are. |  What, none of that is on your list ? :-) - |  So much to see!. | LA ? - well, if you must :-)

Comment: Not to mention (but Greg did :-) ) Grand Canyon (even one side) , Barringer/meteor crater, Sedona, Flagstaff  - the IHOP people gave us the best restaurant service we have ever had (wet night, more staff than customers, ... :-) ) , Hoover dam at night,glimpse of Route 66, Maybe a bit far to [Winslow](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/eagles/takeiteasy.html)  to go [standin on a corner](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=standing+on+a+corner+in&biw=1024&bih=643&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CCEQsARqFQoTCMGRhpSR68YCFebbpgodqGwMmg) maybe not :-).

Comment: We met Elvis with a (real) Edsel in [Kingman](https://www.google.co.nz/maps/@35.5681366,-114.0607166,243273m/data=!3m1!1e3) - but, then, there's LA :-). Such a big world.

Comment: I totally agree with you! Upper and Lower are real different worlds! What pulls me to the LA area is the beach and take my first dive in the Pacific. On the other hand great outdoors on the opposite side!

Which would you consider that shows a bit more of America and Americans?

Comment: Do *not* sleep in your car except in a recognized campground. Dangerous. I'd recommend North Rim of the Grand Canyon if you can find a spot. Second choice, Sequoyah and Kings Canyon Parks. Unless you are particularly interested in the Los Angeles Dodgers, Las Vegas has a minor league (AAA, one level below majors) baseball team and you could go one night during your stay in Las Vegas, if they are in town.